# How to enable Cloud Tool Results API?

Tags: google-app-engine, android-espresso, circleci, google-cloud-test-lab

I am trying to setup Espresso Tests to be executed in Google Test Lab. This needs to be triggered from our CI process (Circle CI), so I am trying to write a script file to do that.

According to google docs you need to enable "Cloud Tool Results API" to do that: https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/continuous#using_product_name_with_jenkins_ci however I can't find anywere this API in google cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Turns our there is a bug in google console and you need to enable "Google Storage Transfer API" in order to see "Cloud Tool Results API". See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-cloud-test-lab-external/Cloud$20Tool$20Results$20API/google-cloud-test-lab-external/01i_L10mONU/U25VSTukAAAJ) for details: